# CSS not loading for a second on load (specific browsers only)

Tags: css, django

Noob question - Have a Django site setup and hitting a weird issue - on some pages and in certain browsers (Firefox) the page loads with no CSS for a split second on load.

Right now it's in development settings with DEBUG/toolbar on and no compression - is that the issue or is there something else at play here?

Note: CSS is concat and minified and served as the first thing on the page.

Comment: It sounds like "flash of unstyled content" (FOUC)

Comment: Huh. Interesting - I didn't know that was an actual thing. Good idea on Wikipedia:    

"front-end developers may choose to hide all content until it is fully loaded, a load event handler is triggered and the content appears."